# RabbitMQ + Spring Integration. Queue size 1, only deleted when override

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp, spring-integration-amqp

I would like to now if is posible to implement this idea with RabbitMQ and Spring Integration:

1. One queue, with capatity for 1 message.
2. The consumers will ask for this message, if it exist in the queue, it will be delivered to them, if not, they get an null or an Error.
3. This message ( if exist in the queue ) will not be deleted for had been download, only will be deleted when the producer put another new message in the queue.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
@Transactional
public Message getMessageFromQueue(String queue) {
    try {
        return this.rabbitTemplate.receive(queue);
    }
    finally {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

With the transaction scope we will poll the queue within transaction. With the `setRollbackOnly()` we rallback TX and, therefore, return the message to the queue back.

Comment: Give me an exception:
**org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope**

Comment: Right, you have to `@EnableTransactionManagement` in your application context, first of all: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction

Comment: Yeah next time. Thk

Comment: I've upvoted to your question: maybe you have already a permission to accept answers. The general problem that people with similar problem will take a look into the solution if they see an accepted answer.

Comment: Looks now at least allow me to participate in meta. I will continue participating to win more permissions. Thanks for the advice and for the upvote